# Codeigniter - .HTACCESS to deny by IP to a folder/controller

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, ip

Inside of my application/controllers folder, I have a sub folder called "cms", where I have my admin tools. I need to restrict access to this folder, and its controllers by IP. I have tried using a .HTACCESS file to do this, as follows (but it doesn't work): This file lives withing /application/controllers/cms/

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from All
Allow from XX.XX.XX.XXX
```

My .HTACCESS file in the root of the application is as follows:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|uploads|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Does anyone know how I can set these two files up to work correctly and allow me to restrict access to the /cms/ folder and its controllers by IP?

I look forward to hearing from you.

Thanks

James

Comment: If you put the first rules in one .htaccess file in the `cms` directory, it should work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this spark:

http://getsparks.org/packages/ip_restrict/versions/HEAD/show

You can have all your CMS controllers extend the CI_Controller method (MY_) and call the spark within the construct.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this and it worked well. I didn't use the installer and instead chose the zipped up version and manually configured it. It worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

So this doesn t work ?
Creating an htaccess file inside the cms folder with the following:

```
order deny, allow
deny from all
allow from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Comment: No, it does nothing when I place this file within the folder /application/controllers/cms. I think that the rewrite engine in the main root .htaccess is clashing somehow, and need to work out how to get this working!